# How to apply Layout scripts and css on MVC partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem using my mvc application layout page styles and scripts within partial views. 
The only way i get it to work is if I add them again on the partial views, which i feel is redundant work.
So, my question is, is there another way to achieve this in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement is not clear. Are you rendering the partial view to a layout page or independently like to a popup or something?

When a partial is loaded into a layout page, it uses the referenced css/js in layout page. Otherwise you need to add reference in partial also.

Comment: thanks for the response. I am loading the partial view independently as a popup and problem when i add the reference to the partial view is that, when i close the popup, it breaks some of the functionality on the normal pages. e.g dropdown menu click/hover event does not work until i click on home, then back to the dropdown item. I hope this is a clear explanation.

Comment: Yes. Then the references should be there in layout as well as partial. This cannot be considered as code duplication.